# How do I change a VirtualizingStackPanel's orientation in code behind?

Tags: c#, windows, gridview, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to add portrait support to a page containing a `GridView` that uses a `VirtualizingStackPanel` as its `ItemsPanelTemplate`. The idea is that when the orientation changes, I'd be able to change the `Orientation` property of the `VirtualizingStackPanel` to scroll vertically in portrait and horizontally in landscape. However, since the `VirtualizingStackPanel` is used as a template, I can't directly access it by name in the code behind.

Is there any way to accomplish what I want?

I could just make a duplicate of the `GridView` (or use a `ListView`) and Visual States to show/hide them appropriately, but I'd prefer not to duplicate so much code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `VisualTreeHelper` to dig into the `GridView's` visual tree and find the panel.

Answer (score 0):

There is some kind of bug when changing the orientation.

```
var zoomedInStackpanel = itemGridView.ItemsPanelRoot as VirtualizingStackPanel;
zoomedInStackpanel.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
```

I gave up and used two GridViews.  One for each orientation